# What do I do when I have a good, off site resource which answers somebody’s question?

Tags: discussion

What's the protocol for the situation where somebody asks a good, valid, on-topic question, and I have a (non-StackExchange) link which answers their question perfectly?

Comments are for requesting clarification, and link-only answers are out. I've also seen it mentioned a few times that replicating content already on other websites isn't cricket.

So what's the deal? Should I just leave it and assume that if I can find it, the OP can find it also? Or is putting that link into a comment OK?

Comment: @KateGregory Missed that one. Also I've been working my way through some of your stuff on PluralSight, really good, thanks!

Comment: much appreciated, though since conversations are offtopic we should probably delete these comments :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two possibilities. If the external content can be summed up in your own words, and the most important information given as an answer that contains a link for further reading, do that.

If the article needs to stand on its own, or you don't want to summarize, post the link as a comment.